# Delete oldest rows from a table where columns are duplicates?

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, delete-row

I have a table `news` with 48 columns

The table has some values like so:

```
ID|title            |date      |.......
 1|Apple iphone 6   |2014-08-23
 2|Samsung Galaxy s5|2014-08-23
 3|LG G3            |2014-08-25
 4|Apple iphone 6   |2014-08-25
 5|HTC One m8       |2014-08-27
```

The "title" value is duplicated in id `1` and `4` (`Apple iphone 6`)

I want to keep the just last ID row in news table and delete the other older rows. 
So in the above example I want to delete row with the ID `1`, keep the last id (`4`) which has the same title column value.

Comment: Are you sure that you need to delete them?

Answer (score 4):

```
delete from news
where id not in
(
  select * from 
  (
     select max(id) 
     from news
     group by title
  ) tmp
)
```

This query groupy by the title and selects the latest `id` for every unique title. Then it deletes all records that have NOT that `id`.

I added another subquery because in MySQL you can't select from a table you are deleting at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Tricky as it is easy to remove non duplicates

1 find the duplicates
2 determine the oldest id's
3 remove only those!

```
delete from news where id in (
   select min(id) from news 
   group by title
   having title in (
      select title from news group by title having count(title) > 1
   )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the most explicit way to do it:

```
DELETE n FROM news n INNER JOIN  news nn ON  n.title = nn.title AND n.id < nn.id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02255f/2

Comment: I run this query but it still runs for about 10min, didnt completed and i killed the query. I have about 250K records in news table so is it very slow query right? And no usefull for me

Comment: What about the answer by @juergen?

Comment: @juergen 's query deleted all duplicated rows. Oldest and newest ids too..

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5dc7/1 not according to this

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, I would do this using a `join`:

```
delete n
   from news n join
        (select title, max(id) as keepid
         from news
         group by title
        ) ti
        on ti.title = n.title and ti.id < keepid;
```

MySQL is finicky in `delete` and `update` statements about referring to the table being modified.  Unfortunately, the typical way to do this in ANSI SQL (and other databases) doesn't quite work:

```
delete from news
    where id < (select max(id) from news n2 where n2.title = n.title);
```

You can get around this with a MySQL hack of using an extra layer of subqueries.